# Is it possible to increase size of only a particular user's home directory (ex: /home/oracle )in centos?

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

I want to install Oracle Database 11g Release 2 on my CentOS 6.6.

For Installation, /home/oracle requires minimum of 5GB.Hence it is failing in 6th step of installation.

(I am following this article http://www.tecmint.com/oracle-database-11g-release-2-installation-in-linux/) How to achieve it ??????

output of df -h looks like:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        18G   14G  3.1G  82% /
tmpfs           491M  232K  491M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       283M   28M  240M  11% /boot
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you increase a KVM guest's disk space?](http://serverfault.com/questions/324281/how-do-you-increase-a-kvm-guests-disk-space)

Comment: You should ask for increasing the size of a partition instead a directory (it doesn't make sense). Oracle has nothing to do with the question you asked. Better give us some info about what resources you have to increase the size: ¿Do you have another HDD or some unpartitioned space?

Answer (score 3):

You Can create new partition and mount that partition on "/Home/Oracle" Directory. You need to add additional volume. If you are on cloud platform like Amazon then you can add additional EBS volume from EC2 service. Create partition with LVM so you can use your space efficiently. Don't forget to make an entry in "/etc/fstab" file for newly created partition.