# Resizing VM's size having only boot partition

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, disk-space-utilization

I've to increase my KVM guest's partition, I followed steps as explained in the accepted answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/324281/how-do-you-increase-a-kvm-guests-disk-space). For step 3, there's a link mentioned in the accepted answer comment section *(tried to paste it here too but my copy paste is not working, if i try writing the whole link, might make mistakes)*.

The problem is that link showed resizing extended disk partitions but there's only single boot partition in my case as shown below:

```
secondaryvm@secondaryvm:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/vda
[sudo] password for secondaryvm: 

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/vda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x622a751e

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *     2048 62912511 62910464  30G 83 Linux

Command (m for help):
```

How should i go with the steps to increase the VM's size in this case? I don't want to loose any data or packages installed currently.

Comment: The easiest approach would be to mount the KVM disk as a non-boot disk in another VM and extend it there. Is there a reason why that approach wouldn't work for you?

Comment: which approach? the approach showed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/324281/how-do-you-increase-a-kvm-guests-disk-space)? I'm scared to proceed further for step3 as I don't know if I might lose data.

Comment: Make a backup before you start, obviously.  It is only 50 GB.

Comment: actually i don't have 50GB space left on the host.